# Executing a program from the command line in Terminal, and writing the path to two files

Tags: python, file, command-line-arguments, execute, sys

I written three different parts of a program (the parts are named tokenize, countWords and printTopMost, and they are placed in a file module called wordfreq) that is going to piece into a complete working program (that I call topmost).

I want the program to be executed from the program, like this:

```
$ python3 topmost.py eng_stopwords.txt examples/article1.txt 20
word                   30
words                  21
count                  11
text                    9
000                     9
counting                7
fiction                 6
novel                   6
rules                   5
length                  5
used                    4
usually                 4
details                 4
software                4
sources                 4
processing              4
segmentation            4
rule                    4
novels                  4
number                  3
```

After the name of the program (topmost) there is paths to two files, and a parameter. I want to access those parameters (or command line arguments) from the program, by importing the module sys, like:

```
import sys
```

and then specify the argument, for instance:

```
sys.argv[1]
```

Here is the code that I have been writing:

```
import wordfreq
import sys
import urllib.request


def main():
    words = wordfreq.tokenize(open(sys.argv[1]))
    words.close()
    frequencies = wordfreq.countWords(words, str(open(sys.argv[2])).strip('\n'))
    frequencies.close()
    wordfreq.printTopMost(frequencies, sys.argv[3])
    # Close the file with the stop words.

main()
```

When I run the program, it gives the result:

```
Erics-MBP:Laboration_1 ericjohannesson$ topmost.py eng_stopwords.txt examples/article.txt 20
bash: topmost.py: command not found
```

What do I do wrong? Where in the code is the cause to the problem?

I you need more information about the program I am trying to write or anything else, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling python correctly.

You need to insert the word `python` into the command line call so that your terminal knows you are using python to call the `topmost.py` file.

Notice that I put `python` after the `$` but **before** `topmost.py`

```
Erics-MBP:Laboration_1 ericjohannesson$ python topmost.py eng_stopwords.txt examples/article.txt 20
bash: topmost.py: command not found
```

Comment: Ok, so does that means that eng_stopswords.txt is the second argument in the command line or does it still count as the first one?

Comment: Still counts as the first one.